# Get columns of a two-dimensional array and place them in a one-dimensional?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

```java
String myData[][] = {
        {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
        {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
        {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
};
```

How to make 3 one-dimensional arrays from one multidimensional array?

```java
String myData1[] = {"test1", "test1", "test1"};
String myData2[] = {"test2", "test2", "test2"};
String myData3[] = {"test3", "test3", "test3"};
```

I need to get

```
myData1 = "test1", "test1", "test1"
myData2 = "test2", "test2", "test2"
myData3 = "test3", "test3", "test3"
```

I used for

```java
for (int i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < myData.length; j++) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible implementation of @khelwood 's comment. You create empty arrays in the beginning and put the values inside respectively.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (j == 0) {
            myData1[i] = myData[i][j];
        } else if (j == 1) {
            myData2[i] = myData[i][j];
        } else if (j == 2) {
            myData3[i] = myData[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

**This will work only if you know the size of the multidimensional array**

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is just to take one array in the multidimensional array like this:

```
String myData [][] = {
    {"test1","test2","test3"},
    {"test1","test2","test3"},
    {"test1","test2","test3"},
};

String[] data1 = myData[0];
String[] data2 = myData[1];
String[] data3 = myData[3];
```

This does exactly the same as the answer from @Narendra_Nath but it is more readable and I would think less expensive.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the columns from a two-dimensional array and place them into separate one-dimensional arrays, you can use the following code:

```
String myData[][] = {
    {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
    {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
    {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
};

int numColumns = myData[0].length; // Number of columns in the array

String myData1[] = new String[numColumns];
String myData2[] = new String[numColumns];
String myData3[] = new String[numColumns];

for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
    myData1[i] = myData[i][0];
    myData2[i] = myData[i][1];
    myData3[i] = myData[i][2];
}

// Print the resulting arrays
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myData1));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myData2));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myData3));
```

This code assumes that the number of rows in the myData array is equal to the number of elements in each column.

The output will be:

```
[test1, test1, test1]
[test2, test2, test2]
[test3, test3, test3]
```

In the code, numColumns is used to determine the size of the one-dimensional arrays. Then, each column element is assigned to the corresponding position in the new arrays myData1, myData2, and myData3 using the loop. Finally, the resulting arrays are printed using `Arrays.toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *streams* as follows:

```java
/**
 * @param matrix rectangular two-dimensional array
 * @param m      number of columns
 * @param n      number of rows
 * @return the transposed matrix
 */
public static String[][] matrixTranspose(String[][] matrix, int m, int n) {
    return IntStream.range(0, m)
            .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, n)
                    .mapToObj(j -> matrix[j][i])
                    .toArray(String[]::new))
            .toArray(String[][]::new);
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] arr1 = {
            {"test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"},
            {"test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"},
            {"test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"}};

    String[][] arr2 = matrixTranspose(arr1, 4, 3);

    // output
    Arrays.stream(arr2).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Output:

```
[test1, test1, test1]
[test2, test2, test2]
[test3, test3, test3]
[test4, test4, test4]
```